# Is the New Maximum Execution Time for a Google App Script for Enterprise for Education Accounts 6 mins / execution?

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the current maximum runtime for Apps Script for users with paid-for licenses, like the former "Google Workspace for Education" upgrade or the newer "Teaching and Learning" upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** It was previously 30 minutes per execution, but it is now unclear if it's being reduced from 30 mins/execution to 6 mins/execution or if Google's documentation is just wrong or incomplete.

### Current Documentation

In the current [quotas documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), there is no explicit mention of quotas for Enterprise (or the equivalent new editions such as the "Teaching and Learning Upgrade") except under the umbrella term "Google Workspace".

**Here, the quota is "6 mins per execution" as in the old days.**

### Former Documentation

One of the [snapshots from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205092647/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) shows the "well-known-but-now-no-longer-documented" fact that business customers had 30 mins per execution was removed from the documentation between December 2020 and January 2021, when the new editions were announced.

### In Practice

I (and others) can in fact still run new or existing App Scripts for up to 30 minutes with paid licenses. In my case, I have an "Enterprise for Education" license, which presumably translates into something equivalent in the new editions until it expires.

However, ominously, there is the statement that quotas "...are subject to elimination, reduction, or change at any time, without notice".

### Conclusion

It is entirely feasible that Google are in the process of reducing the current 30 minute / execution quota and the documentation is preceding the change.

It is equally feasible that Google have not updated their quotas page correctly since the launch of the new editions.

Therefore, there is no clear answer since we may be in the middle of a change (as per the documentation) or the documentation may just be incorrect.

Comment: Wow, never knew they increased the execution limit. Last I needed a big script to run was maybe 2 or so years ago, back then Enterprise had a 6 minute limit as well. I guess they tried giving 30 minutes and decided that the old way was better

Comment: @vytautas Yeah, it wasn't easy to find any announcements. The only mentions I can find now are on the Wayback Machine and some news sites that cover Google updates. There's probably a single slide shown for a few seconds in one of the Next '18 videos but I couldn't find it.  I'm honestly hoping that the documentation is just wrong or incomplete (it wouldn't be the first time for Google).

Comment: To be fair, script documentation for Google Apps is probably the best one out there, I have very rarely seen any issues with their documentation. By the looks of things it indeed was updated somewhere around mid 2018. Last time I worked on my large script that could take over 6 minutes was in April 2018 and it was 6 minutes all-around back then